# Understanding a definition of limit of a set $X$ in real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions, proof-explanation

I was studying about limits in real analysis (from a book Problems of Calculus in One Variable written by I.A Maron) when , I came accross the definition :

> A point $a$ on the real axis is called the limit point of a set $X$ if any neighborhood of the point $a$ contains points belonging to $X$ which are different from $a$ ($a$ may either a proper or an improper point) .

However, I don't get what is meant by $real\space axis$ ,I am considering it as $X$ axis (by drawing an analogy to limit of functions , as it was written on that particular section in the book .) Now, I think this assertion needs a slight modification upon the part:" contains points belonging to $X$ which are different from $a$". This may not be the case if we consider the sequence :$2,2,2...$, right? Thus the number $a$ might be in the neighborhood .Also, I dont understand what is a proper or an improper point ?

Comment: Real axis means the set of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$. So $X$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$  and not a sequence.

Comment: @mowzorn But I think the modification , may be needed as I mentioned in my post ...What do you think ?

Comment: But what do you mean by a sequence? The sequence $\{a_n=2,\quad n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is not a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. You can take a set of all elements in this sequence, but then you get just a single point $\{2\}$.

Comment: @mowzorn True! But what if $a$ occurs in that subset of $\mathbb {R}$?

Comment: Edit: I made a mistake. $a$ doesn't have to be in $X$.

Comment: @mowzorn not exactly! If $X=\{1/n,n\in\mathbb {N}\}$, then $X\subset \mathbb {R}$ and $limX=0\notin X$

Comment: @mowzorn Yep! But I am saying $a$ might be in $X$...then, the assertion needs to be modified...

Comment: But I still don't quite understand your concern about point $a$ being in $X$. For example look at an interval $X=[0,1]$. Any $a$ from that interval is a limit point, because you can find another element of $X$ in any neighbourhood of $a$. Is it a bit clearer?

Comment: The difference between an "adherent point" and a "limit point" is that if $a$ is an adherent point in $X,$ it could be an isolated point, while a limit point must have points in $X$ that are nearby $a.$

Comment: @mowzorn Now, I am totally confused , so , that means the limit of a set may not be unique

Comment: @mowzorn Any set is a particular sequence of distinct real numbers and we know that a sequence has a unique limit ...I am fully confused !...

Comment: To be completely honest, I am now confused by your definition of a set. I think there is some confusion regardnig the definitions that we use. I'm not sure I can be of much help in this case.

Comment: @Doug M Thank you! but I wanted to know about "proper and improper point" about which I dont have any idea ....

Comment: Improper points are $\pm \infty.$  I had to find a copy of the book.  It is defined on page 11.

Comment: @DougM Okay! So all the "finite" points are proper, right? ....

Answer (score 1):

The *definition* (not "assertion") of your book for "limit point of a set of real numbers" is a particular case of "[limit point of a subset in a topological space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accumulation_point)", and needs no "slight modification".

I think your quote is not completely faithful: it should begin with "A point [...] is called *a* limit point of a set", not *the* limit point. It is rarely unique. For instance, the set of limit points (also called the "derived set") of $X=(1,2)\cup\{3\}$ is $[1,2].$

This notion must not be confused with those of limit of a sequence or a function. The *set* $X$ is not a sequence.

The "real axis" is the set $\Bbb R$ of real numbers.

What your book calls "improper point" is probably "real number not belonging to $X$". In that sense, the two limit points $1$ and $2$ of the previous example are "improper".

Another (though less probable) interpretation could be that the author wants to include $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ as "improper" real numbers. In [the topological space $[-\infty,+\infty],$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line) the set of limit points of $(0,+\infty)$ is $[0,+\infty].$